# Window hook is not working in Windows 7 but in Windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-7, mfc, hook

We are migrating our applications from windows xp to windows 7. One of the application is window and mouse hook. same code is working fine in windows xp but it is not working in windows 7 target machine(windows 7 installed with our own software platform).

*One important thing is its working fine in my personal laptop which is having windows 7 os*

i dont know what is happening...

please help me to resolve this...

Answer (score 2):

There are increased security features in Windows 7, and that's probably what you're running into. Try running your app as administrator on your target machine (right click, run as admin).

I haven't tried such a hook in Win7 myself, but I saw this happen from XP to a Vista box.

Comment: Sorry for -1, it happened by mistake, can't undo it now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. actually our application does hook every process we create. i have created 32bit dll. target machine is 64 bit so every process is 64bit right. so it tried to load my hook dll(32bit) into 64bit processes. we cannot load 32bit dll into 64bit exe...... :)